# Maven and wsdeploy task

Tags: ant, maven

What is a good approach to use wsdeploy with maven?

I need to use the wsdeploy ant task with maven.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a little dated, but [this](http://sdudzin.blogspot.com/2007/09/maven-2-and-websphere-automated-build.html) write-up may still be relevant to what you want to  do.

It talks about using ant tasks (wsInstallApp, wsUninstallApp and wsStartApp provided by websphere) in maven.